# Perforce Rollback: Depot or Folder?

Tags: perforce, p4v

this is my first time using the Rollback feature in p4v.

When I select rollback on a submitted changelist, it prompts me for a rollback folder. It then tells me to pick either from Depot or Workspace. My question is what is the difference? The directory structure of the depot and my workspace is identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's for convenience. Some folks like to visualize the depot structure, some workspace.

I do find, though, that some folks use "Rollback..." on a changelist when what they really want is "Back Out Submitted Changelist xxxx" (which puts all the files in that changelist back to where they were before the changelist was submitted).